# Generating a bash script from a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to generate a script from within a script but am having problems because some of the commands going into the new script are being interpreted rather than written to the new file. For example i want to create a file called start.sh in it I want to set a variable to the current IP address:

```
echo "localip=$(ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1  -d'/')" > /start.sh
```

what gets written to the file is:

```
localip=192.168.1.78
```

But what i wanted was the following text in the new file:

```
localip=$(ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1  -d'/')"
```

so that the IP is determined when the generated script is run.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: By the way -- generally speaking, any kind of `grep | tail | awk | cut` sequence means you're doing it wrong. `awk` can do the work of grep, tail *and* cut, and much more efficiently.

Comment: I'd also strongly suggest using `ip -o addr` instead of bare `ip addr` -- that way you get everything on one line.

Comment: ...then again, if your shell is bash, you can also pick the IP address out of the `ip -o addr` output with built-in regex support, thus not needing awk, tail, cut *or* grep at all.

Comment: ...that said, I don't see `state` in my `ip addr` results at all; sure you aren't conflating it with `ip link`?

Comment: Why do you "*need to generate a script from within a script*"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're making this unnecessary hard. Use a heredoc with a quoted sigil to pass literal contents through without any kind of expansion:

```
cat >/start.sh <<'EOF'
localip=$(ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1  -d'/')
EOF
```

Using `<<'EOF'` or `<<\EOF`, as opposed to just `<<EOF`, is essential; the latter will perform expansion just as your original code does.

---

If anything you're writing to `start.sh` needs to be based on current variables, by the way, be sure to use `printf %q` to safely escape their contents. For instance, to set your current `$1`, `$2`, etc. to be active during `start.sh` execution:

```
# open start.sh for output on FD 3
exec 3>/start.sh

# build a shell-escaped version of your argument list
printf -v argv_str '%q ' "$@"

# add to the file we previously opened a command to set the current arguments to that list
printf 'set -- %s\n' "$argv_str" >&3

# pass another variable through safely, just to be sure we demonstrate how:
printf 'foo=%q\n' "$foo" >&3

# ...go ahead and add your other contents...
cat >&3 <<'EOF'
# ...put constant parts of start.sh here, which can use $1, $2, etc.
EOF

# close the file
exec 3>&-
```

This is far more efficient than using `>>/start.sh` on every line that needs to append: Using `exec 3>file` and then `>&3` only opens the file once, rather than opening it once per command that generates output.

Comment: Great answer. Could you elaborate on the difference between `<<'EOF'` and `<<EOF`?

Comment: @MicahSmith, as I say in the text, `<<EOF` runs expansions, so `$(foo)` gets replaced with the output of running `foo`. `<<'EOF'` keeps contents literal.

Comment: @MicahSmith, btw, to speak to *why* all the `printf %q` is necessary -- think of what happens if a variable you want to pass through contains `$(rm -rf /)` -- you want to be very, _very_ sure that stays data and can't get parsed as code. :)

Comment: Thanks All .... cat with the     <<'EOF' solves the issue perfectly.

i'll try to keep it simple from now on ;-)

Comment: One of the things that makes bash tricky is that there's a difference between *looking* simple and *being* simple. I mean, `echo $foo` looks simple, but what it actually does under the hood is a lot more complex than `echo "$foo"`... and that's one of the most trivial examples available.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful discussion @CharlesDuffy