# Writing a bash script from bash script. Lines without interpretation

Tags: bash, heredoc

I want to create a bash script from a bash script. The problem doing it with old echo style (example echo -e "some commands" > /path/to/file.sh) is the commands are interpreted and substituted by its values.

Googling I found this solution on this forum:
[Generating a bash script from a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32077318/generating-a-bash-script-from-a-bash-script)

There, they use:

```
cat >/path/to/file.sh <<'EOF'
    some commands
EOF
```

If I do a mini-script only with this, it works... the problem is while try to integrate in my big script... with a very basic "some commands"... it generates an error:

warning: here-document at line xxxx delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF') ./myscript.sh: line xxxx: syntax error: unexpected end of file

What am I doing wrong? can't be used this inside functions or what's the point of the error... I'm not sure of being understanding what error tries to say. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have `EOF` at the start of the line (i.e. no spaces before)?

Comment: omfg... i have some tabs because in my code is inside a function and I have all indented and beautified... if I remove the tabs on the EOF line it works! it disrupt the beauty of my script, but it works.... I feel like a n00b :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end delimiter for a here-document *needs* to be flush to the left, with no indentation whatsoever, regardless of whether it occurs in a function or elsewhere.

Indentation is allowed, but only with tabs, if the here-document is started with `<<-word` rather than with `<<word` (any initial tabs will then be removed from the start of each line of the here-document).

Also note that if the script that you are outputting with your `bash` script contains here-documents, then the delimiter of those here-documents must be different from the one used to end the contents of the script.

Since the delimiter may be an arbitrary word, it's good practice to use a descriptive delimiter, like `END_SCRIPT`, or similar.

Comment: Thx @Tom Fenech and Kusalananda. It seems cat >/path/to/file.sh <<-'EOF' wins the war